# How do i get the reference of an object in AudioFile and add it to an array audioData within the audioManager class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write code which takes the reference of an object created within the AudioFile class and add them to a list called AudioData within a seperate class called AudioManager which is going to be used to manage instances of AudioFile.

I have tried to do this using an AudioCode and nextCode function which is the requirements of my project and have had no luck as of yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We can’t point out the mistake in your code if we can’t see your code.  Edit your question and show us how you’ve attempted to use these classes.  And explain exactly what result you were expecting, and what you observed instead.